# Breaking out of a while loop from within an inner function's body

Tags: javascript, while-loop, break

If I have:

```
while(foo) {
  var x = bar.filter(function(){ /* any problems with using `break;` here to exit the while-loop? */ });
  bar(), baz();
  // and so on...
}
```

Will there be any weird or unexpected behaviors?

Comment: Explain the original task

Comment: `break;` will not work when called from within the function, so yes problems a plenty

Comment: @zerkms what isn't clear?

Comment: @musefan any workarounds that you know of?

Comment: You can't from within the embedded function.

Comment: This is why @zerkms asked you to explain the original task. What are you trying to do? Under what conditions will you break the loop?

Answer (score 6):

`break` breaks the loop it appears directly within; if you have `break` outside of a loop (or switch) in a function (your `filter` iterator), it's a syntax error.

Add a condition to the `while` which is set by the function:

```
var stop = false;
while(foo && !stop) {
  var x = bar.filter(function(){
    if (someCondition) {
        stop = true;
    }
  });
  bar(), baz();
}
```

Or of course, it could just set `foo` directly:

```
while(foo) {
  var x = bar.filter(function(){
    if (someCondition) {
        foo = false;
    }
  });
  bar(), baz();
}
```

...but I don't know what `foo` is and whether that's reasonable.

If you need `bar` and `baz` not to be executed in the breaking condition, you'll need to add a guard:

```
var stop = false;
while(foo && !stop) {
  var x = bar.filter(function(){
    if (someCondition) {
        stop = true;
    }
  });
  if (!stop) {
      bar(), baz();
  }
}
```

or

```
while(foo) {
  var x = bar.filter(function(){
    if (someCondition) {
        foo = false;
    }
  });
  if (foo) {
      bar(), baz();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can not use `break` in a closure function within a while loop, however, you can e.g. use `false` as an explicit return value to issue a break to the loop:

```
var count = 0,
    foo = true;
while(foo) {
  var bar = function() {
    if (++count < 23) { 
      console.log(count);
      return true; 
    } else { 
      return false; 
    }
  };

  if (bar() === false) { break; }
}
```

For your specific example, because `filter` does not return the return value of your closure function, you have to break the loop by setting a value you defined outside the `while` loop, e.g. `foo` to false:

```
var count = 0,
    baz = [1,2,3],
    foo = true;
while(foo) {
  var x = baz.filter(function(a) { 
    if (a > 2) {
      foo = false;
    }
    return a < 3  
  });
}
```

Comment: -1: Why have you taking it upon yourself to decide the OP no longer needs the `filter` function?

Comment: Oh, I see. I prefer to use a guard - keeps it simpler.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, you cannot use `break` inside the function body.

But depending on what exactly you're trying to acomplish, you could also switch your logic around and don't repeat until a break, but trigger the next iteration from within the function, when needed:

```
function filterFunc() {
    if (condition) {
        iter();
    }
}

function iter() {
    var x = bar.filter(filterFunc);
    bar(), baz();
}
```